# SQL Error : 1064

Tags: php, mysql

Пишет ошибку:

```
SQL Error : 1064 You have an error IN your SQL syntax; CHECK the manual that corresponds TO your MySQL server version FOR the RIGHT syntax TO USE near 'OR ban_email LIKE '' OR ban_email LIKE ''' at line 4

SELECT ban_ip, ban_userid, ban_email FROM phpbb_banlist WHERE ban_ip IN ('4d2d9edc', '4d2d9eff', '4d2dffff', '4dffffff') OR ban_userid = OR ban_email LIKE '' OR ban_email LIKE ''

Line : 461
File : sessions.php
```

Исходный код:

```
if ( $user_id != ANONYMOUS )
    {
        $sql .= " OR ban_email LIKE '" . str_replace("\'", "''", $userdata['user_email']) . "' 
            OR ban_email LIKE '" . substr(str_replace("\'", "''", $userdata['user_email']), strpos(str_replace("\'", "''", $userdata['user_email']), "@")) . "'";
    }
    if ( !($result = $db->sql_query($sql)) )
    {
        message_die(CRITICAL_ERROR, 'Could not obtain ban information', '', __LINE__, __FILE__, $sql);
    }
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в выражении. там явно пропущено (я поставил ##### на месте пропуска). Код, который вы привели, формирует то, что после этого места. Там скорее всего ожидалось некое число, id пользователя.

```
SELECT ban_ip, ban_userid, ban_email FROM phpbb_banlist WHERE ban_ip IN ('4d2d9edc', '4d2d9eff', '4d2dffff', '4dffffff') OR ban_userid = ##### OR ban_email LIKE '' OR ban_email LIKE ''
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT ban_ip, ban_userid, ban_email 
  FROM " . BANLIST_TABLE . " 
  WHERE ban_ip IN ('" . $user_ip_parts[1] . $user_ip_parts[2] . $user_ip_parts[3] . $user_ip_parts[4] . "', '" . $user_ip_parts[1] . $user_ip_parts[2] . $user_ip_parts[3] . "ff', '" . $user_ip_parts[1] . $user_ip_parts[2] . "ffff', '" . $user_ip_parts[1] . "ffffff')
   OR ban_userid = $user_id";

Comment: значит  $user_id пустое или равно пустой строке.